# Evaluates true outside expression but false inside

Tags: python, if-statement, types, python-2.x

I apologise if this turns out to be a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything on this...

(Python 2.7.6)

In essense, I'm using variants of the code below:

```
def isnum(a):
    try:
        float(a)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

that determines if the user input is indeed a number or not.

```
isnum(3)
True

isnum("3")
True
```

If I use the below code:

```
def input():
    while True:
        a = raw_input("Please enter a number:")
        if isnum(a):
            print float(a)
            break
        else:
            print "Please enter only numbers!",a,'is invalid'

input()
```

I'd also like to note that I tried `isnum(a) == True` as well...

I get an the 'enter only numbers' error when I input "3" when prompted!.

```
Please enter a number:"3"
Please enter only numbers! "3" is invalid
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not enter `"3"`, just `3`.

Comment: `float('"3"')` is different than `float("3")`.

Comment: Also, `str.isdigit()` is a builtin that does what your `isnum()` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"3"` is a string containing 3. But when you send it to raw_input, it becomes `'"3"'` which is 3 surrounded by quotes, which is not a number.

Comment: Just realised it myself. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are giving `"3"` as input and not `3`.